# How do you show $\sin(180^\circ - 2x) = \sin(2x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

My approach would be let $2x$ become $q$ and $\sin(180-q)=\sin(q)$ therefore $\sin(q)=\sin(2x)$ but I think there is a better proof.

Comment: @terrace That's not a helpful comment

Comment: @ZiHao if you are serious, then yes, your reasoning is fine

Comment: @ZiHao With your substitution, I agree that it is enough to show that $\sin(180^\circ - q) = \sin(q)$. However, how do you know (or prove that) $\sin(180^\circ - q) = \sin(q)$?

Comment: Why do you think there is a better proof?  If you have the theorem you quote, it is perfectly good.  If you don't, you need something else.  Maybe you know the angle difference formula?  That will prove the formula you quote, or you can use it directly.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I think by using unit circle we can prove it? Let q be the acute angle, and 180-q we have the same angle on the other side as well, so they are the same. Please correct me if this is wrong.

Comment: @RossMillikan Because instead of using this 'assume method', I thought there might a better visualisation prove. But everything is good now. Thanks.

Comment: Your unit circle approach is much harder to formalize than the one based on angle formulae.  I believe it is correct.  The one based on angle formulae also does not depend on $q$ being acute, which is a good thing since what you asked us to prove does not make that restriction.  The unit circle is a good way to visualize trig, but unless you have a way to connect the pictures with algebra it will not provide a rigorous proof.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  Use the subtraction formula $$\sin (a-b) = \sin a \cos b - \cos a \sin b$$ with $a = 180^{\circ}$ and $b = 2x$.  Also note where $180^{\circ}$ lies and how it will affect one of the trigonometric values.